# C# Checking for primitives and string

Tags: c#

I have the following method to replace all key's and values recursively while stepping through json:

```
   private static void ReplaceKeyValue(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, dynamic keys)
    {
        foreach (dynamic item in keys)
        {
            if (dictionary.ContainsKey(item.Key))
            {
                dictionary.Add(item.Value, dictionary[item.Key]);
                dictionary.Remove(item.Key);

                var nextItem = dictionary[item.Value];
                Type type = nextItem.GetType();
                if (type != typeof(string) && !type.IsPrimitive)
                {
                    if (dictionary[item.Value].Count > 0)
                    {
                        ReplaceKeyValue(nextItem, keys);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The code has to check whether the nextItem has any children and then replace all of them again and if not then step out. As soon as the code enters the second level of the json where I have several items with only string and integer values it enters the type check step and then errors with:

```
$exception  {Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Count'
```

I have tried checking for GenericType and GenericTypeDefinition as well to no avail. Please advise on what the best approach would be to check for that? I am missing something simple?

EDIT: To clarify. 
As I said I am looping ovr a json object already deserialized by JSON.net. I am casting to IDictionary because the value type is unknown and can be anything therefore I need to check the type and handle accordingly. If it has children then I need to loop through them as well and do the same. The items can be several levels deep.

EDIT 2:

I resolved it.

I just needed to add a step to check for ExpandoObject so that I dont check for Count and capitilize the type for string from string to String(I thought there is no difference?). Here is the final piece:

```
                if (nextItem is ExpandoObject)
                {
                    ReplaceKeyValue(nextItem, keys);
                }
                else {
                    Type type = nextItem.GetType();
                    if (type != typeof(String) && !type.IsPrimitive)
                    {
                        if (nextItem.Count > 0)
                        {
                            ReplaceKeyValue(nextItem, keys);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: `dictionary[item.Value]` is apparently a string. Have you tried setting a breakpoint there?

Comment: I am. I am then looping through my object to replace the keys because my json object is compressed and I need to decompress it.

Comment: Sounds a little XYish, can you show us what the input looks like

Comment: @EpicKip Obviously hence my question. I saw it is a string, then got the type so that I can check for that and skip the recursive loop. It is not skipping it...

Comment: @Memphis335 Because you are not checking the type of the thing thats giving an error...

Comment: Here is a gist to the json. The last row starting with "_" is what I am replacing them with. [Github gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Memphis335/8c7175a02fa650f678c50a30266bdd82/raw/d1d739e0b78939f18137f2ca258f7239baa3b612/json.json)

Comment: Am I blind? As of `IDictionary<string, object> dictionary` `dictionary[item.Value]` returns an `object`, so that `.Count` shouldn´t even compile. Apart from this a `string` has no `Count`. However it has a `Length`.

Comment: Please, show us obscured version of your JSON, it might clarify what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Here is the current compressed json data. [Current json](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Memphis335/8c7175a02fa650f678c50a30266bdd82/raw/533ff6633fcf74c206ae212201a543956c000c6d/current.json) and here is what I want it to be [ToBe Json](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Memphis335/eca151e97073fa47ac5a36358518de5a/raw/acb867ef4bc4e1e9b87e286aaa99045fdc16eb51/tobe.json)